# Regex whole word

Tags: java, android, regex

I feel a little silly asking this question, but from everything I've read, this should work and it doesn't, for me.  I'm just trying to match a whole word in a string using regular expressions.

So, if I'm trying to find the word "the" in a sentence, it should return true for "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", but return false for "there quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".

I've tried this:

```
 String text = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
 return text.matches("\\bthe\\b");
```

I've also tried:

```
    String text = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    String regex = "\\bthe\\b";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    return matcher.matches();
```

I've also tried this regex: "\bthe\b"

And they always return false.  I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious here, since this shouldn't be too difficult. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, even though I feel more stupid now. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is matcher.find()

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29

Comment: probably a better answer than mine: +1

Answer (score 8):

If you use `matches`, it must match the whole String. `String#contains(...)` may be what you're looking for, or perhaps you want to put some wild cards before and after your word:

```
String regex = ".*\\bthe\\b.*";
```

e.g.,

```
  String text = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  System.out.println(text.matches(regex));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
".*\\bthe\\b.*"
```

Basically, what you are trying to match it against is the string "the", but you need to return a match even if the input has other things, so you need to put ".*" on both sides for that.

Answer (score 0):

Bzzt! It will naturally return `true` for the second sentence, since the word `the` appears two times: **The** quick brown fox jumps over **the** lazy dog". Your second sentence still has the second **the**.

Your regex is correct. However, you'll need to use the `Pattern.find` method instead of `matches`, because `matches` attempts to match against the whole string. `Pattern.find`, on the other hand, will locate substrings that match your pattern.